# sjPlot reorder estimates using plot_models function

Tags: r, sjplot

I'm attempting to plot the regression coefficients of two models in a single plot using sjPlot's plot_models function. I'd like to re-order the variables but cannot figure out a way to do so. It seems that the plot_models function does not have the order.terms or sort.est arguments, like the plot_model function does. Here's my code and plot:

`plot_models(OK, ON, axis.title = "Odds Ratios",transform = "exp", m.labels=c("Treat 1", "Treat 2"), 
            legend.title = "Treatment", axis.lim=c(0.1,10), dot.size = 4)`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsMQG.png

I'd like to switch the order of "six6.dom" and "six6.A" so that "six6.A" is on top. In the model summary of ON, six6.A is listed first. I've also tried reordering my input models in case that would affect the variable order, but it did not.

Any tips would be much appreciated!